# Saving Captured Image in flutter

Tags: android, image, camera, flutter

I am trying to call this function for opening camera and saving the captured photo in flutter. The function is working good and camera opens up but when i try to save the image it always saves the image file in the application directory inside the data instead of saving it in the external location.
How would i be able to fix this mistake ?

```
Future openCameraAndSaveImage(BuildContext context) async {
      File _image;
      final File capturedImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera,
      );

      final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      final String path = dir.path;

      final File finalImage = await capturedImage.copy('$path/image1.png');

      setState() {
        _image = finalImage;
      }

      setState();

      AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(
        content: new Container(
          child: new Text("Image Saved in" + path),
        ),
      );
      showDialog(context: context, child: dialog);
    }
```